# 1st 3 Librarian slots are Mending Books?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Playing Minecraft today and was in the process of making a Mending Librarian. Got the 1st slot Mending for 10 emeralds. 2nd slot was Mending books for 34 emeralds. 3rd was 12 emeralds.
My question is how, lol. It seems impossible for this to happen. Has anybody else expirenced this? I've read about 2 slots in a row, but 3? It blew my mind and just wanna see if anybody else has come across this themselves. Thanks peeps

Comment: Wow, I wish my villagers were like this.
I think this is just really good luck.

Answer (score 6):

If you didn't have mods affecting their rates, then you were just insanely lucky. The odds for getting 3 Mending books is **1 in 50,653**. There are 37 possible enchantments that all have an equal chance of being chosen ([wiki source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#cite_note-enchanted-book-8)).

You also managed to get two of the lowest possible prices - 5 and 6 emeralds, which were then doubled since this is a treasure enchantment. And this is ignoring the fact that getting an enchanted book trade is 1 in 3 at the first three Librarian levels.

Comment: More likely than getting 3 skulls in a row from wither skeletons.